# Getting an object to span multiple [jou]{apa6} columns without colliding

Tags: multicolumn, apa6, includegraphics, journal, layout

I like to use `\documentclass[apacite,jou,a4paper]{apa6}`.
It wastes too much negative space, but it invokes a consistent two column layout, and helps with the APA journal style, referencing, etc. which is nice.

---

[image]

---

But every now and then I want to be able to have an object span both columns. Kind of like a banner. Which it can, but the text in the other column doesn't move out of the way and so they collide and overlap. What can be done about it?

---

[image]

---

**Here's the code:**
<sup>(Essentials are in bold).</sup>

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\title{Example of an APA style for journal article}
\shorttitle{APA style}
\twoauthors{Author One}{Author Two}
\twoaffiliations{Institute of Physics}{Albert's Institute}
\abstract{This is an example of a journal article using the \texttt{apa6.cls} document class to typeset manuscripts according to 6th edition of the Americal Psychological Association (APA) manual}
\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Author One}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Sample section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
~\cite{Einstein}. 

\begin{center}
~\includegraphics[scale=0.48]{diagram.pdf}
\end{center}

\subsection{Sample subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\section{Sample section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\subsection{Sample subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\subsubsection{Sample subsubsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\subsubsection{Sample subsubsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: IIRC in `IEEEtran` we used `\figure*` to get a float that streches both columns. Did you try that?

Comment: apa6 supports figure*, but requires endfloat.  I don't think they like having images in the middle of the text.